# Facebook authentication window as pop up

Tags: facebook

I got the following code from http://nocturnsoft.com/devblog/?p=174 site and everything is working fine. But running into a small UI issue. The login window is not opening in a pop up. Am I suppose to include the js sdk or just use a different code. The pop up is critical part as I will be calling the page with in and iFrame.

Thanks in advance.

```
require_once "src/facebook.php";

$app_id = "xxx";
$app_secret = "xxx";

// Init facebook api.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
));

// Get the url to redirect for login to facebook
// and request permission to write on the user's wall.
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array('scope' => 'publish_stream')
);

// If not authenticated, redirect to the facebook login dialog.
// The $login_url will take care of redirecting back to us
// after successful login.
if (! $facebook->getUser()) {
    echo <<< EOT
<script type="text/javascript">
top.location.href = "$login_url";
</script>;
EOT;

    exit;
}

// Do the wall post.
$facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", array(
    message => "Testing Wall post",
    picture => "http://www.cjp.org/display_image.aspx?ID=348063",
    link => "http://www.cjp.org",
    name => "Combined Jewish Philanthropies",
    caption => "The Jewish Federations of North America"
));
```

Answer (score 0):

the method you are using is only redirecting the user to the application login page. if you want a popup you should use the JS SDK and the FB.login function like explained here :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank for the quick response. The method you mention is working but I want pre populate the messages instead of having user type a messages. 
Thanks, Rex